# Mahalanobis distance for vector-classification

Tags: classification, distance-functions, distance

B"H

Hello,

Assume I have a very large set of vectors ($X_i$) over some feature space ($F_i$), each vector is labeled as either $+1$ or $-1$. For convenience lets refer to this set as "**the history set**".

**THE QUESTION:**

Given a new vector $X_{test}$ to be classified (as either "+1" or "-1"), I'd like to find the **history set** vector which is the closest to the $X_{test}$ vector (**Mahalanobis-distance** wise) and classify $X_{test}$ as that history-vector.

How can I find the closest history-vector?

Comment: **If needed:** I can easily split the **history-set** into 2 sub-sets, each containing all equally-labeled vectors (i.e. one sub-set contains all "+1" labeled vectors, and the other - all "-1" labeled vectors). Features (**Fi**) covariance matrix can also be easily calculated for each of these vector-subsets.

Comment: Why not just calculate the Mahalanobis distance from $X_{test}$ to each $X_i$, using the sample mean and covariance matrix for the appropriate subset (+1, -1) of the $X_i$?

Comment: Gladly, only I don't know how to apply to solution you've suggested. Could you please explain? (Detailed math would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are some differences between the covariance matrices of the $X_i$ classified as $+1$ and those classified as $-1$, you could do the following:

1. Calculate the covariances for the two sets of $X_i$. I'll label them $\Sigma_{+}$ and $\Sigma_{-}$.
2. For all $i$ in the **+**-set:  $d_{test,i} = \sqrt{(x_{test}-x_i)^{\text{T}}\Sigma_{+}^{-1}(x_{test}-x_i)}$.  Similarly for the **-**-set, just using $\Sigma_{-}^{-1}$ instead, obviously.
3. Take the $i$ associated with the minimum $d_{test,i}$ as your closest history-set vector.

The $d_{test,i}$ are the Mahalanobis distances between $X_{test}$ and the $X_i$.

Sample code in R for a single covariance matrix:

```
# Create sample history matrix with 100 entries 
X <- matrix(rnorm(1000),10,100)
# Create sample test matrix
Xtest <- rnorm(10)

# Calculate the Mahalanobis distances
Sigma <- cov(t(X))
SInv <- solve(Sigma)

di <- rep(0, ncol(X))
for (i in 1:length(di)) {
  di[i] <- sqrt(t(Xtest-X[,i]) %*% SInv %*% (Xtest-X[,i]))
}

which.min(di)
```

Comment: Thanks much. **Clarification:** Assuming vectors **Xi** are ordered in rows, so that each column (of the matrix formed by this vector-arrangement) represents a certain feature: Is the covariance matrix you're referring to - the features' covariance matrix?   In other words, assume there are N features (i.e. N columns, i.e. vectors **Xi** dimension is N), the covariance matrix would be of N x N size {and symmetrical as COV(**Fi**, **Fj**) = COV(**Fj**, **Fi**)} ?

Comment: The code above assumed the vectors were in columns, so that each row of $X$ represented a feature.  $\Sigma$ is 10 x 10, and is the covariance matrix of the features, as you thought.